# Unresolved external symbol for the mentioned code in description

Tags: c++, oop, static

```
 #include <iostream>
class t1
{
public:
    ~t1();
    static t1& fun();
private:
     t1()
     { 
     }
};

t1& t1::fun()
{
    return t1();
}

int main()
{
    t1::fun();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting unresolved external symbol. please help. the errors are below

```
Error  2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall t1::~t1(void)" (??1t1@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class t1 & __cdecl t1::fun(void)" (?fun@t1@@SAAAV1@XZ)  D:\LXI\LXIRef\RefDesign_V01.00\Software\Solution\TestWebServer\TestWebServer.obj    TestWebServer
Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   D:\LXI\LXIRef\RefDesign_V01.00\Software\Solution\Debug\TestWebServer.exe    1   1   TestWebServer
```

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, please include the *full* output of the build process. Complete and without editing. Preferably by simply copy-pasting the output as text into the question body.

Comment: A hint about your problem though: Where do you *implement* (define) the `t1` constructor and destructor?

Comment: sorry, i will edit the code, compile and re-post if errors.

Comment: Lastly, if you use the reference returned by the `t1::fun` function you will have *undefined behavior*. Inside `t1::fun` you create a *temporary* object, which will cease to exist immediately. Returning a reference to it is incorrect.

Comment: sorry for wasting valuable time of experts. it worked with destructor definition. but the real problem with some other code which i was trying replicate. Thanks for your time.

Comment: platform mismatch between library and the program caused me the same issue (64 bit & 32 bit). Code is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Give definitions to constructor and destructor.

```
#include <iostream>
class t1

{

public:

    ~t1() {} // <<<< defined here

    static t1& fun();

private:

    t1() {} // << defined here

};

t1& t1::fun()

{

    return t1();

}

int main()

{

    t1::fun();

    return 0;

}
```